# Embedding a Yammer Group in a SharePoint 2007 Wiki

Tags: 2007, wiki, yammer

I'm using a SharePoint 2007 Standard Wiki and have been asked if it's possible to embed a Yammer group into it.  Using the Yammer provided code in the HTML Source doesn't work as it appears that the HTML editor strips out any JavaScript.

SharePoint 2007 also doesn't allow an in-browser page edit, so placing it within a CEWP is also apparently ruled out.

Can anyone think of an approach that I can try?

Comment: Have you tried placing the JavaScript inside `<script></script>` tag?

Comment: I have.  They get stripped out still.